# In subroutine insert: Expected ( error in Jack programming language

Tags: jack, nand2tetris

I get error

> In BinarySearchTree.jack (line 20): In subroutine insert: Expected (
> In BinarySearchTree.jack (line 25): In subroutine insert: Expected (
> I have 2 classes, Node:

```
class Node { 
    field int key; 
        field Node left, right; 
   
    constructor Node new(int data){
        let key = data; 
        let left = null;
        let right = null;
        return this;
    }
    method int getKey() { return key; }
    method Node getLeft() { return left; }
    method Node getRight() { return right; }
    method void setKey(int _key) {let key=_key; return;}
    method void setLeft(Node _left) {let left=_left; return;}
    method void setRight(Node _right) {let right=_right; return;}
}
```

And BinarySearchTree:

```
class BinarySearchTree {
    field Node root;

    constructor BinarySearchTree new() {
        let root = null;
        return this;
    }

    method void insertBST(int num) {
        let root = BinarySearchTree.insert(num,root);
        return;
    }
    method Node insert(int num,Node p) {
        var Node tempNode;
        if (p = null){
            let p = Node.new(num);
            return p;
        }
        if (num < p.getKey()){
            let tempNode = BinarySearchTree.insert(num,p.left);
            do p.setLeft(tempNode);
            return p;
        }
        if (num > p.getKey()){
            let tempNode= BinarySearchTree.insert(num,p.right);
            do p.setRight(tempNode);
            return p;
        }
        do Output.printString("Item in tree and not inserted.");
        return p;
    }
}
```

How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `p.left` and `p.right`.
You can't access fields directly like in other programming languages.

Use `p.getLeft()` `p.getRight()`. The error message means that the compiler doesn't know about expressions that have a "." after an classname, but have no "(" after the methode or function name. So it tells you to add a ( after the function or methodename. It won't check that this isn't a function or methode name, but a field if there are no brackets, so the error message is confusing.